# Threads v/s Input arguments

Tags: c++, pthreads

I am calling a function of my process from different threads of the process. So if the function is called from two different threads at same instant, will it affect the the values of the input arguments? Since these will be maintained in stack.

Answer (score 3):

Each thread gets its own stack, so the answer is no -- the arguments passed in via thread A will not affect the arguments passed in via thread B.

If you want more specifics, maybe you can post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Each thread have its own *Thread local stack* , which are independent of each other . So it won't affect the arguments passed .